# How do I create a symbolic link to mysql? (Mac, XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, macos, command-line, xampp

I have just installed XAMPP and I went to the command line and typed 'mysql' and I got the following error:

"command not found"

When I specify where mysql is located 
"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u root"

it works fine so I'm just wondering how I could create a link so that I don't have to type the full path name each time?

Thanks

Comment: Another way is to change your PATH variable so it includes the directory with mysql

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll want to put it in /usr/bin if you want to be able to type just `mysql`

```
   ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql /usr/bin/mysql
```

Comment: You might need to use `sudo`, also wouldn't be better to use `/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/bin`, since the last one can be upgraded by the system.

Answer (score 1):

ln -s [actual mysql directory] [symlink directory]

i.e.: ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql /home/user/me/mysql